# Você come direito?

Tags: português-brasileiro

Eu ouvi esse frase em lugares diferentes:

No escritório do médico:

> Estava doente e o médico perguntou: Você come direito?

Pareceu para mim que: você tem apetite?

No texto li:

> Ele fuma demais e não faz nenhum exercício físico e não come direito.

Parece para mim que: Não tem uma diate saudavél.

Sim? Qual é significado desse frase?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Comer direito" é uma expressão vaga e ampla, mas essencialmente significa *ter uma dieta saudável*, incluindo aí a qualidade, quantidade e regularidade das refeições.

No exemplo do médico, esse era quase certamente o sentido na pergunta. Para perguntar sobre o apetite especificamente, ou se menciona a palavra, ou se pergunta sobre "*comer bem*".

Comment: Sim, só que fazer algo direito é um registro informal.

Comment: @Lambie Verdade, nesse caso uma alternativa menos informal seria, por exemplo, "comer corretamente".

Comment: Isso. Credo, paso meu tempo  comendo direito mas de vez me dá um troço e  alavanco um jogo de cintura. :)

Answer (score 2):

"Come direito" refere-se a ter refeições balanceadas e saudáveis, não exclui lanches ou fast foods, mas basicamente, se você come mais de forma saudável ou não.

Comment: balanceadas, não. equilibradas.

Comment: @Lambie Na verdade "balanceado" é bastante adequado, cf., e.g., no [Aulete](https://www.aulete.com.br/balanceado): "1. Que contém os nutrientes necessários em quantidades adequadas (refeição balanceada; cardápio balanceado; dieta balanceada).".

Comment: Tudo bem, prefiro equilibrado: Google "refeiçao balanceada" site:.br = 14,400//"refeição equilibrada" pelo mesmo site:.br = 270,000 :)

Comment: @Lambie Aquele primeiro número que o Google exibe é uma estimativa grosseira - é preciso ir até a última página, selecionar para mostrar resultados repetidos e ir para a última de novo, daí o número é (talvez) mais confiável; ele lista 308 para uma e 318 para outra. O [Corpus do Português](https://www.corpusdoportugues.org/now/) também registra apenas uma pequena diferença entre as duas.